# IconWorkshop/Axialis IconGenerator Alternatives

Tags: export, icon

I'm looking for alternatives to IconWorkshop/Axialis IconGenerator for Mac users. Is there a program where you can upload your own SVG and export it to all different kinds of formats? Especially **ICO** and **BMP**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Inkscape to export your file to PNG.
2. Open the PNG in Gimp and export it to a variety of file formats.

Currently, the 2.10 export dialog box does not show the file types dialog. But if you type the correct file extension, you will have the specific dialog box for that file type.

[image]

Comment: Also note that GIMP can also import SVGs, and rasterize them, without the need for the Inkscape step.